# Get two offset points between two points

Tags: coordinates, trigonometry

Hi I need help finding coordinate or points offset from two endpoints of a line. In my program, I would like to specify the two points and the offset. Then I need to calculate the two offset coordinates.

I worked something out using trigonometry but it only works in some cases and when the line is in the positive quadrant.

Here is an image describing what I need to find:
[Points on line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SRlFf.png)

Ok so I need to find X3,Y3 and X4,Y4 coordinates.

My method I followed:
Calculate angle:
Ang = atan((Y2 - Y1)/(X2 - X1))

To find X3:
X3 = X1 + Offset * Cos(Ang)

The same concept for Y3

The issue is that if the line is in a different quadrant the point info is not correct... Any help, please.

Comment: When you say you need to find `<x3,y3>` and `<x4,y4>`, by what means are they specified? From your image, they appear to be 21.3% and 77.6% of the distance between `<x1,y1>` and `<x2,y2>`. So, you specify the end-points and then what, exactly?

Comment: Hi thanks for getting back to me.

Comment: So what I have is a line in space. Just a 2D line between X1,Y1 and X2, Y2 points.

Comment: I then need to find a point along that line with a certain offset. this need to be done on both ends

Comment: Yeah, yeah - i get that. What i still dont know is how the two points of interest are specified. While you say with an offset,  you forgot all the other important info. Like, offset fron which end? Also, offset in what units? pixels, normalized line coordinates or perhaps even percentage? So taking your image as an example, what are the actual values you have to find the two points along it?

Comment: Hi as I mentioned above, I need two offset points from both ends. One point offset X mm from the line end point and the same on the other side. Both offset points to be affset inward on the line. Does that help?

Comment: Okay, cool - that's probably enough. The image you've posted is 2052x1317  pixels. The line's length is about 1249 pixels. X3,Y3 exists 296.5 pixels from one end and the other point is 281.8 pixels from the other.... **SO** if we take all the above measurements to be in mm, it's a trivial task that can be achieved with the use of 2d vectors. Is that a reasonable assumption? That all measurements are in the same units and that the offsets are specified using the number of these units from the closest end? (or starting end p1 - I dunno what you want)

Comment: Yes that's fine. The image is just an illustration but yes the points are offset inward from either side and the offset is supplied in mm units.

Comment: So the line is between P1 and P2. The first offset point (P3) is offset from P1 towards P2. The second offset point (P4) is offset from P2 towards P1.

Comment: Does this make sense now?

Answer (score 1):

This question is a clear case for using 2d vector math. The idea is that we subtract p1 from p2 to give us a vector that describes the length and direction of the line. We then normalize this vector, such that it has a length of 1. If you then multiply this normalized vector with the number of units you'd like to move away from the end and add the result to the end-point, you'll have a new point.

Consider an example walking along the x axis:

p1 = 0,0
p2 = 10,0

dif = p2 - p1 = (10,0)

length is 10, so it's 10 times too long - we divide it by 10 to get a vector 1 unit long.

If we then move 5 times (1,0), we end up at 5,0 - 5 units away, bewdy!

Here's a function that achieves the same thing:

```
function calcOffsetPoint(x1,y1, x2,y2, distTowardsP2fromP1)
{
    var p1 = new vec2d(x1,y1);
    var p2 = new vec2d(x2,y2);

    var delta = p2.sub(p1);
    var dirVec = delta.clone();
    dirVec.normalize();

    dirVec.timesEquals(distTowardsP2fromP1);
    var resultPoint = p1.add(dirVec);

    return resultPoint;
}
```

As you can see, this makes use of something I've called vec2d. There's a copy of it in the following snippet:

```js
"use strict";
function byId(id){return document.getElemetById(id)}
function newEl(tag){return document.createElement(tag)}
window.addEventListener('load', onDocLoaded, false);
function onDocLoaded(evt)
{
 var end1 = new vec2d(0,0);
 var end2 = new vec2d(10,0);
 
 var midPoint = calcOffsetPoint(end1.x,end1.y, end2.x,end2.y, 5);
 console.log( midPoint.toStringN(2) );
 
}

class vec2d
{
 constructor(x=0, y=0)
 {
  this.mX = x;
  this.mY = y;
 }
 get x(){return this.mX;}
 set x(newX){this.mX = newX;}
 get y(){return this.mY;}
 set y(newY){this.mY = newY;}
 add(other)
 {
  return new vec2d(this.x+other.x, this.y+other.y);
 }
 sub(other)
 {
  return new vec2d(this.x-other.x, this.y-other.y);
 }
 timesEquals(scalar)
 {
  this.x *= scalar;
  this.y *= scalar;
  return this;
 }
 divByEquals(scalar)
 {
  this.x /= scalar;
  this.y /= scalar;
  return this;
 }
 dotProd(other)
 {
  return this.x*other.x + this.y*other.y;
 }
 length()
 {
  return Math.hypot(this.x, this.y);
 }
 normalize()
 {
  this.divByEquals( this.length() );
  return this;
 }
 perpendicular()
 {
  var tmp = this.x;
  this.x = -this.y;
  this.y = tmp;
  return this;
 }
 clone()
 {
  return vec2d.clone(this);
 }
 static clone(other)
 {
  return new vec2d(other.x, other.y);
 }
 toString(){return `vec2d {x: ${this.x}, y: ${this.y}}`}
 toStringN(n){return `vec2d {x: ${this.x.toFixed(n)}, y: ${this.y.toFixed(n)}}`}
}

function calcOffsetPoint(x1,y1, x2,y2, distTowardsP2fromP1)
{
 var p1 = new vec2d(x1,y1);
 var p2 = new vec2d(x2,y2);
 
 var delta = p2.sub(p1);
 var dirVec = delta.clone();
 dirVec.normalize();
 
 dirVec.timesEquals(distTowardsP2fromP1);
 var resultPoint = p1.add(dirVec);
 
 return resultPoint;
}
```

I had some spare time over the weekend, so put together a working demo of the image you posted. Have a play around. Make sure you run it in full-screen, so you can see the sliders that set the offsets for p3 and p4. Disregard the coordinate-system transformation stuff, that's just there to allow me to make an image the same dimensions as your image yet conveniently display it in a window with about 5% the area. The questions come from the exercise section of some old text-book I was reading over the weekend.

```js
"use strict";

class vec2d
{
 constructor(x=0,y=0)
 {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
 }
 abs()
 {
  this.x = Math.abs(this.x);
  this.y = Math.abs(this.y);
  return this;
 }
 add(vec1)
 {
  return new vec2d(this.x+vec1.x, this.y+vec1.y);
 }
 sub(vec1)
 {
  return new vec2d(this.x-vec1.x, this.y-vec1.y);
 }
 mul(scalar)
 {
  return new vec2d(this.x*scalar, this.y*scalar);
 }
 plusEquals(vec1)
 {
  this.x += vec1.x;
  this.y += vec1.y;
  return this;
 }
 minusEquals(vec1)
 {
  this.x -= vec1.x;
  this.y -= vec1.y;
  return this;
 }
 timesEquals(scalar)
 {
  this.x *= scalar;
  this.y *= scalar;
  return this;
 }
 divByEquals(scalar)
 {
  this.x /= scalar;
  this.y /= scalar;
  return this;
 }
 normalize()
 {
  var len = this.length;
  this.x /= len;
  this.y /= len;
  return this;
 }
 get length()
 {
  //return Math.sqrt( (this.x*this.x)+(this.y*this.y) );
  return Math.hypot( this.x, this.y );
 }
 set length(newLen)
 {
  var invLen = newLen / this.length;
  this.timesEquals(invLen);
 } 
 dotProd(vec1)
 {
  return this.x*vec1.x + this.y*vec1.y;
 }
 perp()
 {
  var tmp = this.x;
  this.x = -this.y;
  this.y = tmp;
  return this;
 }
 wedge(other)
 { // computes an area for parallelograms
  return this.x*other.y - this.y*other.x;
 }
 static clone(other)
 {
  var result = new vec2d(other.x, other.y);
  return result;
 }
 clone() // clone self
 {
  return vec2d.clone(this);
 }
 setTo(other)
 {
  this.x = other.x;
  this.y = other.y;
 }
 get(){ return {x:this.x, y:this.y}; }
 toString(){ return `vec2d {x: ${this.x}, y: ${this.y}}` }
 toStringN(n){ return `vec2d {x: ${this.x.toFixed(n)}, y: ${this.y.toFixed(n)}}` }
 print(){console.log(this.toString())}
};

class mat3
{
 static clone(other)
 {
  var result = new mat3();
  other.elems.forEach( 
        function(el, index, collection)
        {
         result.elems[index] = el;
        }
       );
  return result;
 }
 clone()
 {
  return mat3.clone(this);
 }
 constructor(a,b,c,d,e,f)
 {
  if (arguments.length < 6)
   this.setIdentity();
  else
   this.elems = [a,b,0,c,d,0,e,f,1];
 }
 setIdentity()
 {
  this.elems = [1,0,0, 0,1,0, 0,0,1];
 }
 multiply(other, shouldPrepend)
 {
  var a, b, c = new mat3();
  if (shouldPrepend === true)
  {
   a = other;
   b = this;
  }
  else
  {
   a = this;
   b = other;
  }
  c.elems[0] = a.elems[0]*b.elems[0] + a.elems[1]*b.elems[3] + a.elems[2]*b.elems[6];
  c.elems[1] = a.elems[0]*b.elems[1] + a.elems[1]*b.elems[4] + a.elems[2]*b.elems[7];
  c.elems[2] = a.elems[0]*b.elems[2] + a.elems[1]*b.elems[5] + a.elems[2]*b.elems[8];

  // row 1
  c.elems[3] = a.elems[3]*b.elems[0] + a.elems[4]*b.elems[3] + a.elems[5]*b.elems[6];
  c.elems[4] = a.elems[3]*b.elems[1] + a.elems[4]*b.elems[4] + a.elems[5]*b.elems[7];
  c.elems[5] = a.elems[3]*b.elems[2] + a.elems[4]*b.elems[5] + a.elems[5]*b.elems[8];

  // row 2
  c.elems[6] = a.elems[6]*b.elems[0] + a.elems[7]*b.elems[3] + a.elems[8]*b.elems[6];
  c.elems[7] = a.elems[6]*b.elems[1] + a.elems[7]*b.elems[4] + a.elems[8]*b.elems[7];
  c.elems[8] = a.elems[6]*b.elems[2] + a.elems[7]*b.elems[5] + a.elems[8]*b.elems[8];
  
  for (var i=0; i<9; i++)
   this.elems[i] = c.elems[i];
 }
 
 transformVec2s(pointList)
 {
  var i, n = pointList.length;
  for (i=0; i<n; i++)
  {
   var x = pointList[i].x*this.elems[0] + pointList[i].y*this.elems[3] + this.elems[6];
   var y = pointList[i].x*this.elems[1] + pointList[i].y*this.elems[4] + this.elems[7];
   pointList[i].x = x;
   pointList[i].y = y;
  }
 }
 
 makeTransformedPoints(pointList)
 {
  var result = [];
  for (var i=0,n=pointList.length;i<n;i++)
  {
   var x = pointList[i].x*this.elems[0] + pointList[i].y*this.elems[3] + this.elems[6];
   var y = pointList[i].x*this.elems[1] + pointList[i].y*this.elems[4] + this.elems[7];
   result.push( new vec2d(x,y) );
  }
  return result;
 }
 
 rotate(degrees, shouldPrepend)
 {
  var tmp = new mat3();
  tmp.elems[0] = Math.cos( degrees/180.0 * Math.PI );
  tmp.elems[1] = -Math.sin( degrees/180.0 * Math.PI );
  tmp.elems[3] = -tmp.elems[1];
  tmp.elems[4] = tmp.elems[0];
  this.multiply(tmp, shouldPrepend);
 }

 scaleEach(scaleX, scaleY, shouldPrepend)
 {
  var tmp = new mat3();
  tmp.elems[0] = scaleX;
  tmp.elems[4] = scaleY;
  this.multiply(tmp, shouldPrepend);
 }
 
 scaleBoth(scaleAmount, shouldPrepend)
 {
  var tmp = new mat3();
  tmp.elems[0] = scaleAmount;
  tmp.elems[4] = scaleAmount;
  this.multiply(tmp, shouldPrepend);
 }
 
 translate(transX, transY, shouldPrepend)
 {
  var tmp = new mat3();
  tmp.elems[6] = transX;
  tmp.elems[7] = transY;
  this.multiply(tmp, shouldPrepend);
 }
 
 determinant()
 {
  var result, a, b;
  
  a =         ( (this.elems[0]*this.elems[4]*this.elems[8])
     + (this.elems[1]*this.elems[5]*this.elems[6])
     + (this.elems[2]*this.elems[3]*this.elems[7]) );
  b =   ( (this.elems[2]*this.elems[4]+this.elems[6])
     + (this.elems[1]*this.elems[3]+this.elems[8])
     + (this.elems[0]*this.elems[5]+this.elems[7]) );
  result = a - b;
  return result;
 }
 
 isInvertible()
 {
  return (this.determinant() != 0);
 }
 
 invert()
 {
  var det = this.determinant();
  if (det == 0)
   return;
  
  var a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i;
  a = this.elems[0]; b = this.elems[1]; c = this.elems[2];
  d = this.elems[3]; e = this.elems[4]; f = this.elems[5];
  g = this.elems[6]; h = this.elems[7]; i = this.elems[8];
  
  this.elems[0] =  (e*i - f*h);     this.elems[1] = -((b*i) - (c*h));     this.elems[2] = (b*f)-(c*e);
  this.elems[3] = -(d*i - f*g);     this.elems[4] =   (a*i) - (c*g);      this.elems[5] = -( (a*f) - (c*d) );
  this.elems[6] =  (d*h - e*g);     this.elems[7] = -((a*h) - (b*g));     this.elems[8] = (a*e)-(b*d);
  
  var detInv = 1.0 / det;
  for (var i=0; i<9; i++)
   this.elems[i] *= detInv;
  
  return this;
 }
 
 reset()
 {
  this.setIdentity();  
 }
 
 print()
 {
  var str = '';
  for (var i=0; i<9; i++)
  {
   if (i && i%3==0)
    str += "\n";
   str += " " + this.elems[i].toFixed(5);
  }
  console.log(str);
 }
}


function byId(id){return document.getElementById(id)}
function newEl(tag){return document.createElement(tag)}
window.addEventListener('load', onDocLoaded, false);

function onDocLoaded(evt)
{
 byId('output').addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove, false);
 byId('slider1').addEventListener('input', onSliderInput, false);
 byId('slider2').addEventListener('input', onSliderInput, false);

 draw();
}

//(400-48)/400 = 0.88
var invMat, svgInvMat;

function onMouseMove(evt)
{
 var mousePos = new vec2d(evt.offsetX,evt.offsetY);
 var worldPos = mousePos.clone();
 invMat.transformVec2s( [worldPos] );
 
 byId('screenMouse').textContent = `screen: ${mousePos.x},${mousePos.y}`;
 byId('worldMouse').textContent = `world: ${worldPos.x.toFixed(1)}, ${worldPos.y.toFixed(1)}`;
}

function onSliderInput(evt)
{
 draw();
}

function updateSliderLabels()
{
 byId('ofset1Output').textContent = byId('slider1').value;
 byId('ofset2Output').textContent = byId('slider2').value;
}

function draw()
{
 var can = byId('output');
 var ctx = can.getContext('2d');
 ctx.clearRect(0,0,can.width,can.height);
 
 var orientMat = evaluateViewOrientationMatrix(0.06*can.width,can.height-24, 0,-1);
 var scaleMat = computeWindowToViewPortMatrix(2052,1317, can.width,can.height);
 var viewMat = scaleMat.clone();
 viewMat.multiply(orientMat);
 
 console.log('viewMat');
 viewMat.print();
 
 invMat = viewMat.clone().invert();
 for (var i=0; i<9; i++)
  invMat.elems[i] /= invMat.elems[8];
 
 ctx.strokeStyle = '#fff';

 var axisPts = [ new vec2d(0,1070), new vec2d(0,0), new vec2d(0.88*2052,0) ]; // xAxis line 88% of image width
 var axis = viewMat.makeTransformedPoints(axisPts);
 drawLine(axis[0].x,axis[0].y, axis[1].x,axis[1].y, ctx);
 drawLine(axis[1].x,axis[1].y, axis[2].x,axis[2].y, ctx);
 
 var lineEnds = [new vec2d(330,263), new vec2d(1455,809)];
 var pts2 = viewMat.makeTransformedPoints(lineEnds);
 
 drawCircle(pts2[0].x,pts2[0].y, 4, ctx);
 drawCircle(pts2[1].x,pts2[1].y, 4, ctx);
 drawLine(pts2[0].x,pts2[0].y, pts2[1].x,pts2[1].y, ctx);
 
 var rawP3 = calcOffsetCoords(lineEnds[0].x,lineEnds[0].y, lineEnds[1].x,lineEnds[1].y, byId('slider1').value);
 var rawP4 = calcOffsetCoords(lineEnds[1].x,lineEnds[1].y, lineEnds[0].x,lineEnds[0].y, byId('slider2').value);
 var ofsPts = viewMat.makeTransformedPoints( [rawP3, rawP4] );
 drawCircle(ofsPts[0].x,ofsPts[0].y, 4, ctx);
 drawCircle(ofsPts[1].x,ofsPts[1].y, 4, ctx);
 
 updateSliderLabels();
}

function calcOffsetCoords(x1,y1, x2,y2, offset)
{
 var dx = x2 - x1;
 var dy = y2 - y1;
 var lineLen = Math.hypot(dx, dy);
 var normDx=0, normDy=0;
 if (lineLen != 0)
 {
  normDx = dx / lineLen;
  normDy = dy / lineLen;
 }
 
 var resultX = x1 + (offset * normDx);
 var resultY = y1 + (offset * normDy);
 
 return {x:resultX,y:resultY};//new vec2d(resultX,resultY); //{x:resultX,y:resultY};
}




// Exercise 6-1: 
// Write a procedure to implement the evaluateViewOrientationMatrix function that calculates the elements of the
// matrix for transforming world coordinates to viewing coordinates, given the viewing coordinate origin Porigin and
// the viewUp vector
function evalViewOrientMatrix(screenOriginX,screenOriginY, worldUpVectorX,worldUpVectorY)
{
 var worldUp = {x: worldUpVectorX, y: worldUpVectorY};
 var len = Math.hypot(worldUp.x, worldUp.y);
 if (len != 0)
  len = 1.0 / len;
 worldUp.x *= len;
 worldUp.y *= len;
 
 var worldRight = {x: worldUp.y, y: -worldUp.x};
 
 var rotMat = svg.createSVGMatrix();
 rotMat.a = worldRight.x;
 rotMat.b = worldRight.y;
 rotMat.c = worldUp.x;
 rotMat.d = worldUp.y;
 
 var transMat = svg.createSVGMatrix();
 transMat = transMat.translate(screenOriginX, screenOriginY);
 
 var result = rotMat.multiply(transMat);
 return result;
}

function evaluateViewOrientationMatrix(screenOriginX,screenOriginY, worldUpVectorX,worldUpVectorY)
{
 var worldUp = new vec2d(worldUpVectorX, worldUpVectorY);
 worldUp.normalize();
 var worldRight = worldUp.clone().perp();

 var rotMat = new mat3();
 rotMat.elems[0] = worldRight.x; rotMat.elems[1] = worldRight.y;
 rotMat.elems[3] = worldUp.x; rotMat.elems[4] = worldUp.y;
 
 var transMat = new mat3();
 transMat.translate(screenOriginX,screenOriginY);

 var result = rotMat.clone();
 result.multiply(transMat);
 return result;
}
/*
0 1 2
3 4 5
6 7 8

translation
-----------
1 0 0
0 1 0
tX tY 1

scaling
---------
sX 0 0
0 sY 0
0 0 1

rotation
--------
cosX -sinX 0
sinX cosX 0
0  0  1
*/

// Exercise 6-2:
// Derive the window to viewport transformation equations 6-3 by first scaling the window to 
// the size of the viewport and then translating the scaled window to the viewport position
function computeWindowToViewPortMatrix(windowWidth,windowHeight,viewPortWidth,viewPortHeight)
{
 var result = new mat3();
 result.scaleEach(viewPortWidth/windowWidth,viewPortHeight/windowHeight);
 return result;
}

// returns an SVGMatrix
function compWnd2ViewMat(windowWidth,windowHeight,viewPortWidth,viewPortHeight)
{
 var result = svg.createSVGMatrix();
 return result.scaleNonUniform(viewPortWidth/windowWidth,viewPortHeight/windowHeight);
}


function drawLine(x1,y1,x2,y2,ctx)
{
 ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(x1,y1);
  ctx.lineTo(x2,y2);
 ctx.stroke();
}
function drawCircle(x,y,radius,ctx)
{
 ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(x, y, radius, 0, (Math.PI/180)*360, false);
  ctx.stroke();
 ctx.closePath();
}
```

```css
canvas
{
 background-color: black;
}
.container
{
 display: inline-block;
 background-color: #888;
 border: solid 4px #555;
}
#screenMouse, #worldMouse, .control
{
 display: inline-block;
 width: calc(513px/2 - 2*8px);
 margin-left: 8px;
}
```

```html
<body>
 <div class='container'>
  <canvas id='output' width='513' height='329'></canvas><br>
  <div id='screenMouse'></div><div id='worldMouse'></div>
  <div>
   <div class='control'>P2 ofs: <input id='slider1' type='range' min='0' max='500' value='301'><span id='ofset1Output'></span></div>
   <div class='control'>P3 ofs: <input id='slider2' type='range' min='0' max='500' value='285'><span id='ofset2Output'></span></div>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
```